# Pyspark RDD collect first 163 Rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Is there a way to get the first 163 rows of an rdd without converting to a df?

I've tried something like `newrdd = rdd.take(163)`, but that returns a list, and `rdd.collect()` returns the whole rdd.

Is there a way to do this? Or if not is there a way to convert a list into an rdd?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not very efficient but you can `zipWithIndex` and `filter`:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda vi: vi[1] < 163).keys()
```

In practice it make more sense to simply `take` and `parallelize`:

```
sc.parallelize(rdd.take(163))
```

Comment: What if I need to subset the rows from > 163 and less than 200 I gave vi[1] > 163 && vi[1] < 200 is not working .Please help

Comment: It worked with below lines of code:             
                                                                   data.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda vi: (vi[1] > 163) & (vi[1] < 200)).keys().count()