# Using Pyspark to create tuples from a line entry of list of words and count using RDD

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, count

I have an RDD composed of a list of 5 words (5 word n-gram), their count, the number of pages, and the number of documents of form
`(ngram)\t(count)\t(page_count)\t(books_count)`.

I am trying to get a final output of the individual words and their counts in the format `(word, count)` using PySpark.

So far, I have used

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x.split('\t')[0].lower().split(' '), x.split('\t')[1])) \
            .collect()
```

in order to get the words in the form

```
[('word_1', 'word_2', 'word_3', 'word_4', 'word_5'], 1),
('word_6', 'word_7', 'word_8', 'word_9', 'word_10'], 3), ...]
```

I am thinking that I need to use some sort of itertools or similar to get the final output in the form

```
[('word_1', 1),
('word_2', 1),
('word_3', 1),
('word_4', 1),
('word_5', 1),
('word_6', 3),
('word_7', 3),
('word_8', 3),
('word_9', 3),
('word_10', 3),
...]
```

However, I have not come across any itertools or other function that will do this.
Since I will be using this on a large dataset, I want to avoid using user-defined functions.

Additional bonus question:
Is there a PySpark RDD function similar to head/tail? I would like to view the top and bottom most frequent words.

So far my thought is to cache the unsorted RDD then use the `.sort()` function with both `ascending=True` and `ascending=False` before using the `.take(n)` function to get the top and bottommost frequent words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [`flatMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=flatmap#pyspark.RDD.flatMap):

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(i, x[1]) for i in x[0]]).collect()
```

Output:

```
[('word_1', 1),
 ('word_2', 1),
 ('word_3', 1),
 ('word_4', 1),
 ('word_5', 1),
 ('word_6', 3),
 ('word_7', 3),
 ('word_8', 3),
 ('word_9', 3),
 ('word_10', 3)]
```

You can also use [`flatMapValues`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=flatmap#pyspark.RDD.flatMapValues):

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).flatMapValues(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'word_1'),
 (1, 'word_2'),
 (1, 'word_3'),
 (1, 'word_4'),
 (1, 'word_5'),
 (3, 'word_6'),
 (3, 'word_7'),
 (3, 'word_8'),
 (3, 'word_9'),
 (3, 'word_10')]
```

Answer to your bonus question: [Pyspark RDD collect first 163 Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213846/pyspark-rdd-collect-first-163-rows)

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. I completely forgot about list comprehension orz